# what limits would cause this script to get stuck?

Tags: python

I'm doing a math puzzle using python, where you find the sequence of digits k digits long where the products of each digit is equal to the sum of the digits, i.e. for k=3 1*2*3 = 1+2+3

I'm new to python and programming in general, and I'm curious why there would be a "drop-off" where it can evaluate to a certain point very fast and after that point the program gets stuck.

```
psnumbers = []

#this gives me a number to start a for loop later in the script
def ones(n):
    string = '1'*n
    return int(string)

#multiplies and adds the digits together and compares the values
def check(n):
    global psnumbers
    add = 0
    mult = 1
    for i in range(len(n)):
        add += int(n[i])
        mult*= int(n[i])
    if add == mult and n[0] != 0:
        print(n)
        psnumbers.append(n)
        return True
    else:
        return False

#starts checking numbers, starting with the value from ones()      
def loop(n):
    for x in range(2,n+1):
        for i in range(ones(x),ones(x)*2):
            if check(str(i)) == True:
                break
            else:
                continue

#loop(23) works for me fine, but loop(n) where n>=24 doesn't finish processing      
loop(23)
```

all values for loop(n) where n <= 23 work exactly how I would like them too and the script finishes in less than half a second. For values of n that are 24 or greater, however, the script generates the values up to what it would output for loop(23) and gets stuck processing. What issues would cause this?

Comment: There isn't a 24 digit number with that property, as far as I can tell. You only really need to check <100 possibilities, the computer will do that basically instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure there is a solution at n=24? I think that your code is working as intended, it will just take a really long time to reach the correct answer. 
I changed your loop so that I'm only looking for the solution at n=24 and am printing out the number it's trying... This will allow you to run it on the command line and will print out the number it's trying, you can see why it takes so long.

```
def loop(n):
    x = n
    for i in range(ones(x),ones(x)*2):
        print('\r' + str(i), end='')
        if check(str(i)) == True:
            break
        else:
                continue
    print('done')
```

it is a significantly higher number.

`n=23 >> 11111111111111111111228`

`n=24 >> 111111111111111112163473` before I hit the jupy notebook limit.

I'm not sure if you have time for a computer to solve it say you can check 1000 numbers a second it would take you `10^24 * 10^-4 = 10^20 seconds`... or `1.15740741 × 1015 days`. You could probably do some tricky logic to avoid checking the same numbers twice (112 == 121 for your algo).

The answer to your question  "why does this take longer" is that the answer is much further away from your starting point for n=24 than n=23.

Answer (score 1):

Your code quits after finding a single solution for any given string length.  As it happens, there is a simple solution handy for any value of `n` up through 23.

However, when we get to n=24, the overhead of all the leading `1`s finally slips past the various numerical properties of small numbers, and there is no such solution.

I changed the instrumentation on your algorithm find *all* such numbers and added a simple `time()` call before and after each loop.

```
def loop(n):
    for x in range(2,n+1):
        start = time()
        for i in range(ones(x),ones(x)*2):
            check(str(i))
        print(x, time() - start)
```

The timings for the first few values of `n` are

```
n     time (sec)
2 0.00010895729064941406
3 0.0007987022399902344
4 0.008989572525024414
5 0.08109426498413086
6 0.6398007869720459
7 6.47220778465271
8 70.14981818199158
```

You can speed this up quite a bit if you write your code to handle only non-decreasing sequences (digits are sorted in numerical order), and put in checks to ensure that the product is within the range of the sum.